# String to pandas dataframe Name too long error

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, csv

Having a comma separated string.When i export it in a CSV file,and then load the resultant CSV in pandas,i get my desired result. But when I try to load the string directly in pandas dataframe,i get error Filename too big. Please help me solve it.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* (not images) **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. The code should be a [mre].

Comment: "try to load the string directly in pandas dataframe"<--- How? Please share.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. Actually it was showing that behaviour for large strings.
I used

```
import io
df= pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(str),sep=',', engine = 'python')
```

It solved the issue..str is the name of the string.